# Hackerearth Question: Monk and the Magical Candy Bags

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I was trying to solve a beginner problem on implementation of priority queue.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/heapspriority-queues/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-the-magical-candy-bags/description/

But my solution fails on the last three test cases. Idk why. I also read the editorial but the solution seems pretty similar to my solution. Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Here is my code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define fast ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define all(x) x.begin(), x.end()
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define foreach(it, v) for(__typeof((v).begin()) it = (v).begin(); it != (v).end(); it++)
#define MOD 1000000007
#define dbg(x) { cout<< #x << ": " << (x) << endl; }
#define dbg2(x,y) { cout<< #x << ": " << (x) << " , " << #y << ": " << (y) << endl; }

/* __builtin_popcount(), __builtin_popcountll() // return no. of set bits 

   next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()) 
*/

void solve() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    ll a;
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a, pq.push(a);
    ll count = 0;
    while (k--) {
        count += pq.top();
        pq.push(pq.top()/2);
        pq.pop();
    }
    cout << count << "\n";
}

int main() {
    fast;
    int t = 1;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
        solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't know how to use a debugger. But thanks for the suggestion. Can you guide me to some resources for learning it?

Comment: Different debuggers, for different compilers, for different operating systems, work in fundamentally different ways. Whicever debugger you have, it should have some kind of documentation, if not, there's always www.google.com, which will do a much better job finding appropriate resources for you than a complete stranger on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score -1):

You used `int` for the element type of `priority_queue`, so it may cause overflow.

Use `priority_queue<ll>` instead of `priority_queue<int>`.